# convert HOC data to time series in python

Tags: python, date, types, type-conversion, adc

I have data in HOC format..

**Input :**

```
SID Start Date  End Date    Ratio ABC
1   1-Jan-22    31-Mar-22   1.111
2   1-Feb-22    31-Mar-22   2.222
```

I am looking for the output :

```
SID as_of_date  Ratio ABC
1   31-Jan-22   1.111
1   28-Feb-22   1.111
1   31-Mar-22   1.111
2   28-Feb-22   2.222
2   31-Mar-22   2.222
```

how should I do it?

tried to run in loops, but it fails.

Comment: What did you try so far? What did you expect? What happened instead?